# Can we edit chrome devtools layout?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I wanna know if it's possible to edit chrome/chromium devtools layout.

The reason is with a x Width > actualWidth, the layout is the left one (this is what i want as full time layout) and over the x Width < actualWidth, the layout change with the right one and I got square monitor so I can put the width too much if I want to see my render and the code javascript side-by-side.

So does it have a way to edit the devtools layout? If there is a way, how I can change the devtools layout?

[Layout sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKi0M.png)

Note: I'm using the right layout (dock to right)

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tab area for the content you are editing. On each side there is an icon that looks like a triangle towards a sidebar. Click that and it will hide the sidebar it is beside to give you more space.

Beyond that, you can click the overflow menu in the primary panel menu (the three icons beside the close button) and then select "Dock to Bottom" from the top layout choices.

Finally, the latest method available is to go into the Settings. Then under "Appearance" find `Panel layout` and change that to horizontal. This will then force the panels in elements and sources at least to be at the bottom always.

Each of these methods should provide you more area to work.

Comment: The third one was what I am searching for. I'm kind of blind because I pass on the settings 3 times and didn't see that option. Thank you.